# ansible-galaxy install fails when specifying a version in requirements

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

Not sure if this is a bug in `ansible-galaxy`, but I'm trying to install roles from a requirements.yml file ([related ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/galaxy.html#advanced-control-over-role-requirements-files).)  One of those roles is being pulled from git, with a specific `version` like so:

**requirements.yml**:

```
---
- src:  https://github.com/thom-nic/ansible-shell
  name: thom-nic.shell
  version: develop
```

When I run `ansible-galaxy install` I get the following output:

```
± ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml --force
- executing: git clone https://github.com/thom-nic/ansible-shell thom-nic.shell
- executing: git archive --prefix=thom-nic.shell/ --output=/var/folders/cw/9vh4w77n4vb_bchhsxnglrcm0000gn/T/tmpF4GAqD.tar develop
- command git archive --prefix=thom-nic.shell/ --output=/var/folders/cw/9vh4w77n4vb_bchhsxnglrcm0000gn/T/tmpF4GAqD.tar develop failed
  in directory /var/folders/cw/9vh4w77n4vb_bchhsxnglrcm0000gn/T/tmpIyYaJz
- thom-nic.shell was NOT installed successfully.
```

If I change the `version` to `master` it works.  I've tried this with other roles in git repos with the same result.

Oddly, `ansible-galaxy` itself doesn't seem to have a `--version` output however `ansible --version` reports v1.8.3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/10358). In the meantime, as a workaround, modify the version in requirements.yml as shown below:

```
---
- src:  https://github.com/thom-nic/ansible-shell
  name: thom-nic.shell
  version: remotes/origin/develop
```